# Android - getting GPS coordinates on service thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, gps

I've been working on an application that tracks a users GPS coordinates and intermittently sends updates to my server. This is done in a thread within a service. Most of the time the first reading will be accurate but when moving the GPS is not updating. I think this is because the LocationManager takes some time to warm up. The location setting on the device will also affect the outcome (Device only, high accuracy), sometimes resulting with 0.0 being returned. Is there a simple solution that will allow it enough time before the values are decided upon?

Service thread:

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            // prepare looper
            Looper.prepare();

            // send text messages
            String numbersList = helper.getNumbers();
            if (numbersList != "") {
                String numbersArray[] = numbersList.split(", ");
                for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
                    sendSMS(numbersArray[i], incident_id);
                }
            }

            // run until told otherwise
            while (active == true) {

                // check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                    accuracy = gps.getAccuracy();

                } else {
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
```

GPS Tracker Class:

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;


            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else if(isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first location always is the last known location `(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(...))`. This location may be relativly old, for example the last fix of the GPS before it was turned off or before you entered a building. Its accurracy in relation to your current location is more or less random (unless you did not move or left the building using the same door).
If the GPS was turned off or the satellites were not visible for a while (e.g. inside a building) the hardware will need some time to get a fix on the current location. This is the delay you are seeing. Afterwards your location listener (not shown above) will get updates from the GPS.